# Как написать "на столько"?

Tags: орфография

- Сколько времени вы вместе?
- На столько мало, что каждый день короток. И на столько много, что будто бы мы знаем друг друга долго.

Answer (score 1):

**Настолько** - наречие, пишется слитно с приставкой **на-**; может быть заменено другим наречием - **так**.

Answer (score 0):

Наречие пишется слитно. Следует отличать от выражения "на столько вёрст продвинулись".
Есть пояснительное слово "вёрст".